# Empty file when uploading to s3 bucket in lambda with multipart/form-data

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

In my lambda I try to store file in the s3 bucket which is sent with `multipart/form-data` content type.
I use `cgi.FieldStorage` to parse.

File is stored and has correct amount of pages, but they are empty. Any ideas why?

Here is my code:

```
def get_file_from_request_body(headers, body):
    fp = BytesIO(bytes(body, "utf-8"))  
    environ = {"REQUEST_METHOD": "POST"}
    headers = {
        "content-type": headers["Content-Type"],
        "content-length": len(body)
    }

    filename = ""
    file = ""
    fs = FieldStorage(fp=fp, environ=environ, headers=headers)
    if "fileName" in fs:
        filename = fs["fileName"].filename
        file = fs["fileName"].value
    logger.info(filename)
    return [filename, file]


def lambda_handler(event, context):

  filename, file = get_file_from_request_body(
        headers=event["headers"], body=event["body"]
    )

  s3_response = s3_client.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=filename, Body=file)
```

Here is my event["body"]:

```
'body': '----------------------------682889305252363295194753\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="fileName"; filename="testfile15.pdf"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n\r\n%PDF-1.4\n%äüöß\n2 0 obj\n<</Length 3 0 R/Filter/FlateDecode>>\nstream\nx��]K��\x11�ϯ�s��\x12)�@À��>��\x009\x04�e�[��%\x7f?⣪�")�{�]�\x03b�ٶM��b���=����~����4l\x7f9�^Ƨ՚���_���OO�N�m����o���ܼ}�,�6��?���a��������`N�u\x18�?�`O�������l�?����:��3?����G��:\\�Sa����\x04�S�=���~z����]��6�/}�A\x1fok�!�fLZ-R���~�(Hd�?��ω(�Ɨ����\x1a_�?��t�c�1L\x15\t̤D\x1a���N3���\x08c��g��\x1e\r�0.<\x7f͔�����<�%��ul�V\x1a\x17���\x08R{�6�_�\x14ygi��\tg�!m\nx<o\x14���4,oxA\x1a�J\x17\x19\x1av��#~�#vj\x0b4�W̜#c���\x0e�g{�q�\\\x18��N�?...
```

And here is what I get in fs["fileName"].value with bytes as a type:

```
b'%PDF-1.4\n%\xc3\xa4\xc3\xbc\xc3\xb6\xc3\x9f\n2 0 obj\n<</Length 3 0 R/Filter/FlateDecode>>\nstream\nx\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd]K\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\x11\xef\xbf\xbd\xcf\xaf\xef\xbf\xbds\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\x12)\xef\xbf\xbd@\xc3\x80\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd>\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\x009\x04\xef\xbf\xbde\xef\xbf\xbd[\xef\xb...
```

s3 response:

```
S3 Response: {'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'SWSA542X4VG7MBQQ', 'HostId': 'cXp0uQITqWDAp***', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amz-id-2': 'cXp0uQITqWDApX*****', 'x-amz-request-id': 'SWSA542X4VG7MBQQ', 'date': 'Mon, 04 Apr 2022 16:02:31 GMT', 'x-amz-version-id': '_mLsbfNIlLrnDi9cNKF89D_wGVHU7jZD', 'etag': '"0550cd4cb9058a7e00a1c466f1fa8e50"', 'server': 'AmazonS3', 'content-length': '0'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}, 'ETag': '"0550cd4cb9058a7e00a1c466f1fa8e50"', 'VersionId': '_mLsbfNIlLrnDi9cNKF89D_wGVHU7jZD'}
```

Request:

```
{'resource': '/api/v1/organizations/{organizationId}/documents/files', 'path': '/api/v1/organizations/rPncmVCGAqnjWTAaaUUkIVPXyfAWtkAXhqFjHiSziDkLdGSHgNwYFiBsCCLHhyHC/documents/files', 'httpMethod': 'POST', 'headers': {'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------503233452686245782492191', 'Host': '**********.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com', 'Postman-Token': '4d2b7352-e41a-4778-b139-31f70986211b', 'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.28.4', 'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': 'Root=1-6****', 'x-api-key': '***', 'X-Forwarded-For': '91.86.215.218', 'X-Forwarded-Port': '443', 'X-Forwarded-Proto': 'https'}, 'multiValueHeaders': {'Accept': ['*/*'], 'Accept-Encoding': ['gzip, deflate, br'], 'Cache-Control': ['no-cache'], 'Content-Type': ['multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------503233452686245782492191'], 'Host': ['**********.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com'], 'Postman-Token': ['4d2b7352-e41a-4778-b139-31f70986211b'], 'User-Agent': ['PostmanRuntime/7.28.4'], 'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': ['Root=1-624b1695-0c24f188632313b41ef5aeb7'], 'x-api-key': ['*********'], 'X-Forwarded-For': ['******'], 'X-Forwarded-Port': ['443'], 'X-Forwarded-Proto': ['https']}, 'queryStringParameters': None, 'multiValueQueryStringParameters': None, 'pathParameters': {'organizationId': 'rPncmVCGAqnjWTAaaUUkIVPXyfAWtkAXhqFjHiSziDkLdGSHgNwYFiBsCCLHhyHC'}, 'stageVariables': None, 'requestContext': {'resourceId': 'xc0pyi', 'resourcePath': '/api/v1/organizations/{organizationId}/documents/files', 'operationName': 'pushFileForDocumentForOrganization', 'httpMethod': 'POST', 'extendedRequestId': 'QEB3VGupliAFTcg=', 'requestTime': '04/Apr/2022:16:02:29 +0000', 'path': '/dev/api/v1/organizations/rPncmVCGAqnjWTAaaUUkIVPXyfAWtkAXhqFjHiSziDkLdGSHgNwYFiBsCCLHhyHC/documents/files', 'accountId': '*******', 'protocol': 'HTTP/1.1', 'stage': 'dev', 'domainPrefix': '**********', 'requestTimeEpoch': 1649088149145, 'requestId': '82c53fae-7659-4883-ae32-34dd99022d58', 'identity': {'cognitoIdentityPoolId': None, 'cognitoIdentityId': None, 'apiKey': 'Fw8jBmPtee4RdFJH9t9IL6IM5wK2VvP83VkEpsiO', 'principalOrgId': None, 'cognitoAuthenticationType': None, 'userArn': None, 'apiKeyId': 'xj3thcn3di', 'userAgent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.28.4', 'accountId': None, 'caller': None, 'sourceIp': '91.86.215.218', 'accessKey': None, 'cognitoAuthenticationProvider': None, 'user': None}, 'domainName': '**********.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com', 'apiId': '**********'}, 'body': '----------------------------503233452686245782492191\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="fileName"; filename="testfile15.pdf"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n\r\n%PDF-1.4\n%äüöß\n2 0 obj\n<</Length 3 0 R/Filter/FlateDecode>>\nstream\nx��]K��\x11�ϯ�s��\x12)�@À��>��\x009\x04�e�[��%\x
```

Comment: if you log/print  `event["body"]` in the lambda is the `file` populated with the expected bytes?

Comment: @LucasRoberts I've edited my question, added logs

Comment: great thanks, could you also add the (non-sensitive parts of the) `s3_response`? Basically, the status code.

Comment: @LucasRoberts done. content-length is 0

Comment: The `content-length` in the response is the length of the body of the ***response message***, not the upload itself. It is usually 0 even on a successful upload of an object to s3.

Comment: I just tested this for myself locally w/a BytesIO object uploading to a personal bucket. I used a pdf 1.7 file and this worked fine. So I'm not sure what is causing the content of the pdf to not be recognized on your end.  As a side comment, I would include an `ContentType='application/pdf'` in the put object, this should not impact the validity of the uploaded object though. It just makes it readable as a pdf in the console which is handy for checking.

Comment: @LucasRoberts My ContentType is "multipart/form-data", which is inserted by Postman automatically when you use it. I added my full lambda event content. Could you please look if you see something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243591/discussion-between-lucas-roberts-and-nataliya-le-loup).